# Do I realy need this html-dtd folder for xhtml?

Tags: xhtml, doctype, dtd, strict

I asked myself, which function has a **html-dtd folder** with this files:

```
xhtml-lat1.ent
xhtml-special.ent
xhtml-symbol.ent
xhtml1-frameset.dtd
xhtml1-strict.dtd
xhtml1-transitional.dtd
```

I downloaded it from a German site, which recommend it when using xhtml.

Do I realy need it, if my head already looks like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Maybe somebody could also explain what these files actualy do.

Comment: Shouldn't that German website be the one to teach you? Could you at least link to it? Why are you trusting information you don't understand?

Comment: You might need them if you have any programs other than browsers reading your XHTML.

Comment: @Marcus Müller: 1. No it did not. 2. Yes, if I would remember the direct link of selfhtml.org - 3. Sensless question - I do not trust, thats the reason why I am here. Also I ask for an explaination. - So please avoid this reproachfully wording sound.

Comment: Hi @DevaStore, didn't mean to insult you :( Well, the point is that you're right on so many levels, which gives me the feeling you quite well understand what these files do! Thus, the question 3. was not meant to be harsh, but really was asking "Ok, you seem to be aware that browsers don't need those files, but some general XML parsers might, so why are you asking *actually*, ie. what are you planning to do?"

Comment: @Marcus Müller: No I realy do not understand, what action these files take. I would not ask, if I would! Selfhtml.org only recommend it for using xhtml without any statement. Its like "If you use this doctype upload these files". - Ok, is forgotten... ;-) And no I was not aware, that browser do not need these files. Actually this was my question - sorry for could not making this clear!

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm currently browsing through selfhtml -- good lord, I haven't been there since 1999 or so; things have changed!

Comment: @DevaStore: Using the best of my Google-Foo, I only found this forum [thread](http://forum.de.selfhtml.org/archiv/2006/7/t132688/) which solved the issue of a non-browser XML parser not being able to understand XHTML by downloading the DTDs from the URLs, and putting them locally alongside with the XHTML files. I think as long as you don't need to use an XML parer that doesn't understand how to fetch DTDs from remote locations, you'll be fine without.

Comment: Yeah thank you, I think so too now. - I thought selfhtml would update his content, but in my eyes its still a good html lexicon anyway.